# Data transfer problems to an array and slowness when access data compared to matlab

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matlab

I'm trying to port a code from matlab to python, my major problem is reading the file and tranposing the data to arrays.
In matlab:

```
[filename,pathname,~] = uigetfile('*.out');
data{1} = importdata(fullfile(pathname,filename), '\t', 8);
unit = dados{1}.colheaders;
title = strsplit(char(dados{1}.textdata(7,1)));
```

In python:

```
import tkinter.filedialog
import numpy as np
def openfile():
    file_path = tkinter.filedialog.askopenfile(mode='r', filetypes=[('','.out')])
    data=np.loadtxt(file_path,delimiter='\t',skiprows=8)
    nrows, ncols = np.shape(data)
    return data, nrows, ncols
data, nrows, ncols = openfile()
print(data[0:5][0])
```

But when i try to access the first column (time vector) and then print this vector, i got the print of a line. Even if i invert the indices from [0:5][0] to [0][0:5] i got a similar result.
Another problem, is that accessing files takes much longer than in matlab.
Below a sample of data which i'm trying to access in python.

```
#
Predictions were generated on 07-Jun-2021 at 07:36:56 using OpenFAST, compiled as a 64-bit application using double precision at commit v2.5.0
 linked with  NWTC Subroutine Library; ElastoDyn; InflowWind; AeroDyn; ServoDyn; HydroDyn; MoorDyn (v1.01.02F, 8-Apr-2016)

Description from the FAST input file: IEA 15 MW offshore reference model on UMaine VolturnUS-S semi-submersible floating platform

Time    NcIMUTVxs   NcIMUTVys   NcIMUTVzs   NcIMUTAxs   NcIMUTAys   NcIMUTAzs   NcIMURVxs   NcIMURVys   NcIMURVzs   NcIMURAxs   NcIMURAys   NcIMURAzs
(s) (m/s)   (m/s)   (m/s)   (m/s^2) (m/s^2) (m/s^2) (deg/s) (deg/s) (deg/s) (deg/s^2)   (deg/s^2)   (deg/s^2)
    0.0000   0.000E+00   0.000E+00   0.000E+00  -7.319E-01  -3.911E-01  -1.344E+00   0.000E+00   0.000E+00   0.000E+00   4.008E+00  -1.493E+01   4.163E-01
    0.0250  -1.818E-02  -9.621E-03  -3.261E-02  -6.358E-01  -3.754E-01  -1.210E+00   9.613E-02  -3.609E-01   9.976E-03   3.542E+00  -1.345E+01   3.672E-01
    0.0500  -3.140E-02  -1.845E-02  -5.898E-02  -5.513E-01  -3.181E-01  -9.064E-01   1.709E-01  -6.537E-01   1.772E-02   2.361E+00  -9.933E+00   2.434E-01
    0.0750  -4.459E-02  -2.540E-02  -7.653E-02  -3.923E-01  -2.385E-01  -4.594E-01   2.103E-01  -8.428E-01   2.174E-02   7.456E-01  -4.845E+00   7.446E-02
    0.1000  -5.177E-02  -3.032E-02  -8.156E-02  -2.350E-01  -1.594E-01   5.288E-02   2.078E-01  -8.920E-01   2.140E-02  -9.449E-01   9.618E-01  -1.022E-01
```

Answer (score 0):

`numpy.loadtxt` is, in general, not very efficient (numpy save/load works best with binary format). Plus your code as-is doesn't work for me (because the delimiter is not really a tab, but rather multiple spaces, and I don't think that's supported by numpy).

In your position I would either use raw python (and then convert to numpy array) or pandas (probably slower but more robust).

Ignoring the tkinter part and just supposing the file name to be `data.txt`, the first solution would look like:

```
import numpy as np

data = []
with open('data.txt') as fp:
    for i, line in fp:
        if i >= 8:
            data.append([float(x) for x in line.split()])
data = np.asarray(data)
```

The second solution with pandas would be:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('data.txt', skiprows=7, delimiter=' ', skipinitialspace=True)
data = df.values
```

The results are equivalent, but the slightly different: python's `split` function automatically trims white space at beginning and end, plus it considers any white space as one separator (one space, multiple spaces, tab, etc.). The conversion to `float` works in the example you provided. All the first 8 rows are skipped. Pandas' version also ignores multiple spaces, but I think it wouldn't work with tabs, plus we need to explicitly tell it to ignore the whitespaces at the beginning of the line. We also just skip 7 lines there, not 8, because by default csv files must have the column names in the first column. So in this particular case, we would get a dataframe with column names

```
['(s)', '(m/s)', '(m/s).1', '(m/s).2', '(m/s^2)', '(m/s^2).1',
       '(m/s^2).2', '(deg/s)', '(deg/s).1', '(deg/s).2', '(deg/s^2)',
       '(deg/s^2).1', '(deg/s^2).2']
```

But that doesn't matter anyway, because when we take `.values` in the end, only numeric values are kept.

Perhaps, the more important difference is that if there is an invalid value at some place (say, a string), python's code would raise an exception when trying to convert to float, pandas' solution will happily accept it and create a column of "object" type (i.e. "anything" type) and not convert even valid entries to float (in that column).